# sed match the 2nd occurrence of the pattern

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

Updating the question:

I have a file that contains block of code in one of the two formats mentioned below:

1.

```
    $Subj .= "HAD PROBLEMS";

    if ($To) {
        $Cc = "abc\@example.com";
    }
    else {
        $Cc = "abc\@example.com";
    }
```

2.

```
    $Subj .= "HAD PROBLEMS";

    if ($To) { $Cc = "abc\@example.com"; } else { $Cc = "abc\@example.com"; }
```

I need to replace the email id in $Cc variable(2nd occurrences)  with a new email id for both the formats.

I have the following sed command to do so.

```
sed '\|HAD PROBLEMS|,/}/ s/$Cc = \(\"[A-Za-z0-9]*\)\(.*\)\([A-Za-z0-9]*\)\@example.com\"/\$Cc = "new email\\@example.com"/' test.txt
```

This command will replace the email id only for the `$Cc` variable in the if `{}` block (first occurrence of `$Cc`) since my ending match pattern is a '}'. I want to replace email id in the second `$Cc` as well. how do i match on the 2nd occurrence of `'}'`  ?

The solution mentioned below works for the first format. But I need a generic solution that works for both the formats. Can anyone please help.

I hope the description is clear.

Comment: Your input is not clear, fix the syntax issues in the script with a proper expected output.

Comment: Why are you setting $Cc to the same value irrespective of $To?  Is that a typo?

Comment: @Inian, your sed script does indeed replace both the instances, but that's not what the OP is looking for. He only wants the *second* instance that appears in an `else` block of an `if` that is after the words `HAS PROBLEMS`. While this might very well be something that could be expressed in sed, it would likely require use of sed's hold space and a snippet like `x;s/[a-z]+\\@[a-z.-]+/new@example.com/2;p`, once you figure out how to get only the important chunk of the file into sed's hold space. Too late at night for me to figure that out, so ... awk to the rescue!

Comment: @ghoti: If only the requirement had been _this_ clear! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that awk would be a clearer language in which to express this problem.

```
awk '/HAD PROBLEMS/{x=1} /}/{x++} x==2&&/\$Cc =/{sub(/[a-z]+\\@[a-z.-]+/,"new@example.com"); unset x} 1' input.txt
```

Or, spaced out for easier commenting:

```
# search for your start pattern, set a counter.
/HAD PROBLEMS/ {x=1}        

# increment the counter at the first close-squigly.
/}/ {x++}                   

# If we've done our increment and we're on the right line,
x==2 && /\$Cc =/ {          
  # substitute the existing address with a new one,
  sub(/[a-z]+\\@[a-z.-]+/,"new@example.com");
  # and reset our counter.
  unset x
}

# Print the current line.
1
```

Comment: This works for me. But I have to do an in place search and replace. I have awk version 3.1.5 running and I cannot do inplace with above command. Is there sed version of the above answer? That would be really helpful.

Comment: Sed inplace simply copies the file to a temporary file, then renames. You can do this yourself with a shell wrapper.  `awk '/HAD PR...' file.txt > output.$$ && mv output.$$ file.txt`

Comment: It is working. Need one more help from you. I have similar code in single line. But the same solution is not working. Does it look for '}' in new line only? Can you help with this?                                                                                $Subj .= "HAD PROBLEMS";
      if ($To) { $Cc = "xyz\@abc.com"; } else { $Cc = "xyz\@abc.com"; }

Comment: SO comments are a terrible place for code, especially if it's unformatted. Please update your question and we'll go from there. Also, are you asking for help with the code that my answer was intended to modify? That may be grounds for a new question, since *this* question is simply about modifying a text file.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have updated the question.